# Recursion with multplie input values

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, depth-first-search

I have function that takes two values as input and returns a value that is a "combination" of the two via a second function (for simplicity, `f2` returns the sum of the input value). In python it is:

```
f1 (in1, in2):
    return f2(in1,in2)

f2 (in1, in2):
    return in1 + in2
```

Now, `in1` and `in2` are associated to a time point; `in1` can take 3 values: `0`,`1` and `2`. 
What I want to do is "look ahead" for `n=4` time points and identify the best sequence of `in1` values that will give me the highest return value.
So, let's say `in2` initially is 10. What I need to do is evaluate:

```
a = f1(0, 10)
b = f1(1, 10)
c = f1(2, 10)
```

Then, for every result that I obtained I need to evaluate it with the possible values of in1:

```
a0 = f1(0, a);  a1 = f1(1, a); a2 = f1(2, a)
b0 = f1(0, b);  b1 = f1(1, b); b2 = f1(2, b)
c0 = f1(0, c);  c1 = f1(1, c); c2 = f1(2, c)
```

So I stop after n iterations and identify the best sequence of inputs (in this example it will be `2 2 2 2` because `10+12+14+16` is the highest value).
Can recursion (Depth-first search maybe) be used in this instance? What is the best approach to code it? A brute force approach is to nest 4 for loops, but what if `n = 10`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the mathematical nature of f1 and f2 beforehand, then you should formulate this as a mathematical program (e.g. using the PuLP library if f1 and f2 are linear with respect to in1 and in2).

Here is the example you mentioned modeled using PuLP and solved using CBC:

```
from pulp import *

model = LpProblem("Maximize f1", LpMaximize)

in1 = LpVariable.dicts("in1", 0, 2, LpInteger)
in2 = 10

model += in1 + in2  # f1 and f2 combined

model.solve()

print(in1.varValue)
```

Although this problem is trivial (in1=2). Not sure how your time periods come into this, as you didn't specify an time-dependence of f1 or f2.

If you don't know the form of f1 and f2, and cannot assume that they are continuous, smooth or convex with respect to in1 and in2, then you might need to brute force it and calculate for all the (in1, in2) combinations. Depth-first and breadth-first will take the same amount of time to exhaustively calculate them.

Comment: No, unfortunately I have no clue about the mathematical nature of the function.